# Python tesseract extract data from image in proper column sequence

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm trying to extract data from below image but i get the output in a very bad format and i'm having trouble to determine right column for right value programmatically..

My progress so far: I've managed to get all the values correctly and the only problem now is that i cant determine using program correct column for each value.. Please guide me how can i achieve this

I have an idea to split the image column-wise then put it through ocr but also dont know how to split image without breaking the text/words

[image]

Above is the image i'm trying to extract data from.. and below is the output

[image]

Comment: From what I know, tesseract is not great for something like this. You can get tesseract to give you the bounding box of every character it finds and from that you can figure out the columns. Use the `image_to_boxes` command. [Documentation is here](https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract/blob/master/README.rst). This will probably only be useful if  you have a lot of documents with this identical format.

Comment: Hey.. Thanq for your time... I think image to boxes will only highlight every character but still return the data in above format right?